# How do you select a data from another table with matching criteria from one table in mySQL query database? Later to compare and get data that we need

Tags: mysql, sql

Q: **Write a query to display the customer ID, customer’s first name, last name, and the total number of reservations in the year 2022.**

So basically I'm trying to match the CustomerID in the customer table with the CustomerID in the transaction table to get the customer's details (ID, name, etc) in the customer table and take the CustomerID from the customer table as well to match it to the CustomerID in the transaction table to get the customer's ID for customers that have made reservations or bookings in the year 2022 and calculate the total number of bookings later for each of the customer's on the year 2022.

I'm not quite sure how to do it but I gave it a shot however it didn't work.

Attached is my solution & the error it gave me. Thank you.

My solution:

```
SELECT
    CustomerID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    CustomerID
FROM 
    customer
WHERE
    customer.CustomerID = transaction.CustomerID 
AND transaction.TransactionDate >= '2022-01-01'
```

The error:

> #1052 - Column 'CustomerID' in field list is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but you need to explicitly join to the transaction table.  And also, you should use aliases.

```sql
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.FirstName, c.LastName
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN `transaction` t
    ON c.CustomerID = t.CustomerID 
WHERE
    t.TransactionDate >= '2022-01-01';
```

Comment: Oh I see. I have another question, what if on top of that I want to deduce like for each customer how many reservations did he/she made on the year 2022? How should I do that?

Comment: You should ask a new question.  This site is not a blog site where you keep asking new follow up questions in the comments.